# appending syntax for appending div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function Build(div_id) {
   var con = '<div>';
      $.each(div_id, function () {
         con += 'iuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuyy' + '<br/><br/>';
      });
      con += '</div>';
      $('#' + div_id).append(con);
 }
```

on my client aspx file I have lots of divs.
every div has id number `<div id='somenumber...

the function above gets div_id and needs to append data into specific div.

`$('#' + div_id).append(con);` in this line I'm trying to append `con` which has the data that I want to append and `div_id` is the div id number which I want to append to.

Comment: Please describe a little more detailed what you want to do and what doesn't work.

Comment: what are you tring to do, what is items?

Comment: Does `items` hold any elements?

Comment: Some more details would be welcome.

Comment: @Kristina88 need edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function Build(div_id) {

   var con = $("<div/>");
    $.each(items, function () {
    con.append('iuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuyy' + '<br/><br/>');
    });
    $('#' + div_id).append(con);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3nigma/ZcnMK/

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your last line to

```
$('#' + div_id).append($(con));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you iterate over the items, I guess items is some kind of array. This would mean you have to do something like this:

```
$.each(items, function (n,value) {
   $('#' + value).append(con);
});
```